# Migrate Ruby on Rails from Postgres to mysql - equivalent to activerecord-postgres_enum?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to install an existing Ruby on Rails project locally on my dev server where I run everything on mysql... the project however was built with Postgresql in mind. I am trying to change all parameters and to run "gem install" and yarn and then setup the db with "rails db:prepare" but I got stuck as there's a gem "activeRecord-postgres_enum" which obviously I commented out... but then the db creation fails:

```
undefined method `create_enum' for ....
```

How do I resolve this? Do I need to alter the actual ruby code or is there a gem that does the equivalent for ENUMs in mysql space that the above mentioned does for Postgresql?

Comment: Can't speak to the enums but you'll probably run into a lot of other problems, would probably be faster and easier to install PostgreSQL and develop on that. Database portability is difficult and Rails/ActiveRecord doesn't offer much help.

Comment: thanks... I thought one of the reasons to have ActiveRecord as an abstraction layer on top of the dbms is exactly to ensure portability but heyho :)

Comment: That's one of the common claims but it really doesn't hold up if you do anything more than `select * from table`. Column types are different, quoting is different, case sensitivity is different, ...